# Mean Centering a Tensor in torch7

Tags: linear-algebra, torch

I was wondering if there was an easier (or more efficient) way to perform a mean centering operation?

Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
data = torch.Tensor{
   {40,  6,  4},
   {44, 10,  4},
   {46, 12,  5},
   {48, 14,  7},
   {52, 16,  9},
   {58, 18, 12},
   {60, 22, 14},
   {68, 24, 20},
   {74, 26, 21},
   {80, 32, 24}
}

x = torch.Tensor(data:size(2)):fill(0)
centeredData = torch.Tensor(data:size())

x:addmv(1/data:size(1), data:t(), torch.ones(data:size(1)))
torch.addr(centeredData:t(), data:t(), -1, x, torch.ones(data:size(1)))

-- double check it's mean centered:
assert(torch.mean(centeredData,1) == torch.zeros(1,data:size(2)), "not centered")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mean = data:mean(1)
data:add(-1, mean:expandAs(data))
```

Comment: Is this the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I think so. expandAs is a free operation, there is no new memory allocated or copied, so it is also pretty efficient. Think of this as a broadcasting paradigm for torch.